# Change of order of differentiation and limit of function sequences defined on open unbounded set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

The following is a well-known fact, which is proved in section 7.17, in Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin.

**Suppose $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of functions, differentiable on $[a,b]$ and such that $\{f(x_{0})\}$ converges for some point $x_{0}$ in $[a,b]$. If $\{f_{n}'\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$, and $$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}'(x)$$**

I guess this result can be extended from a closed compact set $[a,b]$ to an open unbounded set ,e.g., whole real line $R$. My strategy is to reduce $R$ to a sequence of closed and compact sets $E_{n}$ s.t. $E_{n+1}\supset E_{n}$, $\cup _{n}E_{n}=R$ and $x_{0}\in E_{n} \forall n$, then prove the limit function $f_{E_{n}}$exist for each $E_{n}$. You can guess that the final step is to make $n$ go to infinity to get $f_{R}$.

My question is 1) Is the generalization of the result right or wrong? nonexample? 2) If the generalized result is OK, do you think my strategy will work? I am not clear how to do the final step, which let $n$ go infinity.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $f_n$ converges **uniformly** to $f$, only **locally uniformly**. The rest of the statements remain true, however, and can be proved using your approach.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks for correction. Do you know where I can find a formal proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to restict yourself to locally uniform convergence. Then the statement is true also for $\mathbf R$. The following holds:

> **Proposition**. Let $f_n \colon\def\R{\mathbf R}\R \to \R$ be differentiable functions, such that $\bigl(f_n(x_0)\bigr)$ converges for some point $x_0 \in \R$ and $(f_n')$ converges locally uniformly. Then $(f_n)$ converges locally uniformly to a differentiable $f \colon \R \to \R$ and 
>   $$ f' = \lim_n f_n' $$

*Proof*. Let $E_k = [x_0 - k, x_0 + k]$. By the theorem in your post, we have that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $E_k$ for each $k$. As each compact subset of $\R$ is contained in some $E_k$, $(f_n)$ converges locally uniformly. $\Box$

To see that uniform convergence on the whole of $\R$ does not hold in general, consider $f_n(x) := \frac xn$. Then $f_n'(x) = \frac 1n$ converges uniformly(!) to $0$, $f_n$ converges at $x_0 = 0$, but $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to $0$, as $\|0 - f_n\|_\infty = \infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, especially for the good example. So the argument that  if $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $[x_{0}-k,x_{0}+k]$ and keeps the good property in the interval for all $k$ then it also does on whole $R$ is OK? without need of special care? I just wanna be careful about the tending-to-infinity step, since sometime it may invite some trouble.

Comment: No, everthing fine here. Note that if we denote the limit of $(f_n)$ on $[x_0 - k, x_0+k]$ by $f^k$, we have $f^{l}|_{[x_0 - k, x_0+k]} = f^k$ for $l\ge k$, hence we have convergene (locally uniform) on the whole of $\mathbf R$